# Dynamic content not updating after form submission in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, dom-events

It shows after I hit the save button again, so basically **it's a step behind, it updates the database but loads after second click**.
Something is definitely wrong with my code:

```
const fetchTweets = async () => {
        let tweets = await axios.get(url);
        return tweets.data.response;
    }
```

Then a function which is being called on page load:

```
const showTweets = async () => {
        let tweets = await fetchTweets();
        let list = ''
        let tweetsElement = document.querySelector('#tweets')
        for(let tweet of tweets) {
            list += tweetFormat(tweet);
        }
        tweetsElement.innerHTML = list;
    }
    showTweets()
```

But when I submit handle the form using this, it won't update the page even though I am calling **showTweets()** function:

```
const tweetFormElement = document.querySelector('#tweet-create-form');
    document.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const url = event.target.getAttribute('action');
        const method = event.target.getAttribute('method');
        axios({
            method: method,
            url: url,
            data: formData
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        showTweets() // <-- calling it here
    });
```

The data shows on the page when I click submit again, but then it updates the database TWICE.
Please if someone could help.

Comment: I found a workaround, I am now calling the fetchTweets() function inside .then(res) right after console.log(). It is working, NOT SURE if it's the right way to do it though.

Comment: Yep, that's how you should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the request to finish before loading the tweets.

Move `showTweets` inside the `.then`:

```
axios({
  method: method,
  url: url,
  data: formData
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
  showTweets()
})
```

Additionally, you probably meant to add the submit listener to `tweetFormElement` only instead of the entire document:

```
tweetFormElement.addEventListener('submit', // ...
```